# Terraform - data resource access in AWS cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I writing a terraform script and I want to use `data resource` to get Kafka MSK related resources, such as Kafka cluster ARN, Kafka Topic ARN.

for example -

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "content_bucket" {
  bucket = "nameof-bucket-from-another-account"
}
```

and I'm wondering if terraform supports getting such resources cross AWS accounts?

I searched but could not find anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

Terraform itself does not care or know about accounts.

Whether the **AWS provider** supports this depends on the actual resource:

- it works for [S3 buckets](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket) because buckets are not account-scoped but have a global ARN and therefore the name is enough to basically address cross-account
- e.g. [KMS keys](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/kms_key) work if you specify the full ARN
- e.g. [IAM roles](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_role) do not work because they fundamentally do not support cross-account access

Even for resources that do not themselves support cross-account access you can have a terraform config with multiple AWS providers with different account configs.

Obviously all this only works if the entity executing terraform has the proper IAM permissions do retrieve the targeted information / access the targeted resource.

Comment: Thank you for the response, so in my case I need Kafka ARNs, such as topic ARN, group ARN. This means that the user I use to run terraform needs to have access to both accounts then?

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev you talking about MSK? Not sure if MSK supports cross account access (to management APIs), does not look like it on first sight.

Comment: Yes, MSK but for management, its for consuming and producing messages.

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev hmm, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kafka/describe-cluster.html supports a `--cluster-arn` argument which might suggest it works cross-account. The AWS provider generally does not do anything magic. If you cannot achieve a cross-account access with regular CLI commands or API calls then the provider will not be able to do it either. Therefore I would suggest to try the aforementioned CLI call and try to e.g. describe clusters cross account and see what happens. (You should have included the fact you are interested in MSK in the question). I have not used MSK.

Comment: Sorry for that, thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if can be helpful, i never tried something like that, but i think you can use Assume Role for access from your AWS account to another account.

In this way you can set another provider in Terraform with an alias and use it in the data source.

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = var.aws_default_region
  access_key = var.aws_access_key_id
  secret_key = var.aws_secret_access_key

}

provider "aws" {
  alias      = "second_account"
  region     = var.aws_default_region
  access_key = var.aws_access_key_id
  secret_key = var.aws_secret_access_key

  assume_role {
    role_arn = var.account_role_arn
  }
}

data "aws_s3_bucket" "content_bucket" {
  provider = aws.second_account
  bucket = "nameof-bucket-from-another-account"
}
```

I am not sure if is possible to use provider aliases also in the Data Source, if you try please keep me updated, I will edit the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # only access inside organization account only  
      # account-1
        provider "aws" {
          
          region = "us-east-1"
          assume_role {
            role_arn="arn:aws:iam::***********:role/role" //paste from 2nd account role arn
          }
        }
# 1st account credentials only dot not use other credentials
    [default]
    access_key = "*********"
    secret_key = "*********"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).